# Issue saving a string as ISO date format

Tags: date, groovy

I'm trying to save a date to MongoDB from FullCalendar in my Grails application.

I'm trying to parse the string `2015-12-27T00:00:00.000Z` into the below format:

```
def startDate = new Date().parse("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",it.start)
def endDate = new Date().parse("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",it.end)
```

But, weirdly when I print the formatted date, I get `Sun Dec 28 05:30:00 IST 2014`. I don't know what or how that particular date is picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use lowercase `y` for year. Uppercase `Y` is for "Week year".

```
new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", "2015-12-27T00:00:00.000Z")
===> Sat Dec 26 19:00:00 EST 2015
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
println new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX").parse("2018-07-30 09:57:15 +0800")
```

Comment: Can you add some details?